# Ember.js (1.2.0): get id into contained field

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a scenario where a contained view is rendered and I need to get the id specified in the outermost view and set it in the contained view.

Html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    Contained Ember.TextField(how do I get id ? ):
    {{view Controls.ContainedField id="containedField"}}
    <br/>
    Direct Ember.TextField(gets id):
    <div>
    {{view Ember.TextField id="directField"}}
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="FieldContainer">
    {{view view.ContainedView}}
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

Controls = Ember.Namespace.create();

Controls.FieldContainer = Ember.View.extend({
    ContainedView: undefined
})

Controls.ContainedField = Controls.FieldContainer.extend({
    templateName: 'FieldContainer',
    ContainedView: Ember.TextField.extend({})
})

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
```

In the `ContainedView: Ember.TextField.extend({})` I have tried:

```
ContainedView: Ember.TextField.extend({
    idBinding: 'parentView.id', // this
    elementIdBinding: 'parentView.id', // and this
    init: function() { // and event this
        var id = this.get('parentView.id'); // in order to set on the contained view
    }
})
```

But for the life of me I cannot get the id for the contained field that was specified in the main handlebars.

Any help will be appreciated.  Here is the jsFiddle illustrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/EbenRoux/Xrb7Y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around. By specifying 'elementId' for the 'root' parentView, rather than 'id', I can set the Id.

Handlebars:

```
{{view Controls.ContainedField elementId="containedField"}}
```

JavaScript:

```
Controls.ContainedField = Controls.FieldContainer.extend({
    templateName: 'FieldContainer',
    ContainedView: Ember.TextField.extend({
        init: function(){
            this._super();
            this.set('elementId', this.get('parentView.elementId') + 'Input');
        }
    })
})
```

jsFiddle with solution: http://jsfiddle.net/EbenRoux/Xrb7Y/5/

Comment: Why are you setting the id on two elements to the same value?  Which is what the markup is producing in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Oops! Well spotted :) --- fixed

Answer (score 1):

Its generally not a good idea to override the `id` of elements generated by Ember - Ember establishes that the binding works through these ids only. What you can do is attach your own properties to these elements by using attributeBindings as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EbenRoux/Xrb7Y/)

Comment: I think you linked back to my jsFiddle.  Anyhow, we generate ids all over the show.  Unfortunately this requirement has been around from before I started on the project.  It works fine everywhere else but I just cannot get the id from the 'root' view.